# Prove the basis in a signal space

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

Let X be a set of signals on the domain D = {−6, −5, . . . , 4, 5} :

X = {hxϕ,A[n]i | n ∈ D, A ∈ R, ϕ ∈ [0, 2π[ }

Consider the following signals from X:

b1 = sin((π/6)*n + π/8), b2 =0.5*sin((π/6)*n +(5π)/8)

prove that the set B = {b1, b2} is a basis of X!

Im currently struggling with this task. The problem i have with the proof of linear independency is because of the discret values in our domain D. Any help for solving this problem would be welcome. i already proved the span of the basis.

Comment: Your definition of $X$ is very confusing. I'd recommend using MathJax on this site for formatting math text. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference